# How can I see the length of the item in the list instead of it being 1 all the time

Tags: list, csv, python-3.7

I want to make a simple program that "removes" items from a list that aren't
a specific length, but all the lengths are 1.

```
import csv

numberofcharacters = int(input("how many characters should the words have?"))

newlist = []

with open("C:\\Users\\stepk\\Desktop\\textexample.txt") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\n")
    for i in csv_reader:
        print(len(i))
        if len(i) == numberofcharacters:
            newlist.append(i)
        else:
            print(i, " is getting removed")

print(newlist)
```

I expected:

```
how many characters should the words have? 3

5
['these']  is getting removed
4
['just']  is getting removed
```

...
(expected something like this)

```
["idk","are"]
```

...

but i got:

```
how many characters should the words have?3
1
['idk']  is getting removed
1
['these']  is getting removed
1
['are']  is getting removed
1
['just']  is getting removed
1
['random']  is getting removed
1
['words']  is getting removed
1
['in']  is getting removed
1
['a']  is getting removed
1
['text']  is getting removed
1
['ducument']  is getting removed
[]
```

Comment: `i` is the *entire row* retrieved from the CSV file, which apparently always has one item in your case.  `i[0]` would be that one item.

Comment: Thank You very much, very stupid mistake, I can't believe I didn't think of that!